# Prove that every first degree equation in $x$ and $y$ always represents a straight line.

Tags: analytic-geometry

Prove that every first degree equation in $x$ and $y$ always represents a straight line.

My Attempt:
Let the first degree equation in $x$ and $y$ be 
$$ax+by+c=0$$.
Let $A(x_1, y_1)$, $B(x_2, y_2)$ and $C(x_3,y_3)$ be any three points in the locus of the given first degree equation. Then,
$$ax_1+by_1+c=0$$
$$ax_2+by_2+c=0$$
$$ax_3+by_3+c=0$$

Now, how should I complete?

Comment: How do you define "a straight line"?

Comment: @5xum, The collection of collinear points that has no end.

Comment: Unfortunately your definition is circular. "Collinear" means "lying on a straight line", hence you have defined "a straight line" to be "a collection of points lying on a straight line that has no end".

Comment: @blue_eyed_... How do you define "colinear"?

Comment: @5xum, lying on the same straight line.

Comment: @blue_eyed_... I hope you are joking.

Comment: if you take two Points say $$A(x_1,y_1)$$ and $$B(x_2,y_2)$$ and $$A\neq B$$ you can compute the Parameters $a,b,c$

Comment: @5xum, For what purpose?

Comment: @blue_eyed_... You define "being colinear" as "lying on the same straight line". And you define "straight line" as "a collection of colinear points". This means that a "straight line" is "a collection of points lying on the same straight line". The definitions are circular, and therefore useless.

Comment: @5xum, I know those things. Please say me the correct ones.

Comment: @blue_eyed_... To me, $ax+by+c=0$ is the **definition** of a straight line.

Comment: Without knowing where you got this problem from, we cannot tell you "the correct ones". That's why we are asking you. Did this problem come from a book, and if so how does that book define a straight line? Or, where else did this problem come from, and how is a straight line defined in that source?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

Show the vectors $\overrightarrow{AB}$ and  $\overrightarrow{AC}$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your hint?

Comment: Do you know any criterion for linear dependence?

Comment: No... I don't....

Comment: In this case you just have to write their coordinates $(x,y)$ and $(x',y')$ are proportional, i.e. $xy'=x'y$. Check this relation for the two vectors.